# Can someone explain mood of sentence begining with " Can I say of..."

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence, mood

A paragraph from Charles Dickens' *David Copperfield*:

"...**Can I say of her face** - altered as I have reason to remember it, perished as I know it is - that it is gone, when here it comes before me at this instant, as distinct as any face that I may choose to look on in a crowded street? **Can I say of** her innocent and girlish beauty, that it faded, and was no more, when its breath falls on my cheek now, as it fell that night? **Can I** say she ever changed, when my remembrance brings her back to life, thus only; and, truer to its loving youth than I have been, or man ever is, still holds fast what it cherished then? "

Comment: I think he's describing the girl he likes/loves, seeing how he holds those memories to his heart.

Answer (score 1):

It is a rhetorical question that needs no answer. All your examples fit the pattern of:

Can I admit A to be true, when all my feelings point to its not being true?

This means that despite A being factually true, I feel and wish the opposite to be true.

Can I say she is dead, when my memories of her are so vivid?